# how to search any word in entire view folder in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many **.cshtml** pages available in view folder of my MVC project. In my layout page there is search option available, so when someone search by any word, then I want to search that word in all **.cshtml** pages and return view name.
how can i achieve this in MVC?

Comment: You need a search indexing engine such as [Lucene .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/) or [Elastic Search](https://damienbod.com/2014/10/01/full-text-search-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-and-elasticsearch/) or one of the many 3rd party search indexing APIs. There is nothing built into MVC to do a search. Also, you probably don't want to search your *views*, since usually most of the *content* is added to the views through a view model. You should index the *content* you are putting in the view model instead.

Comment: you mean we need to index our entire text to databases like elastic search and search from there. right?

Comment: Yes. For best performance you should index out of band from when you search. You index the site once and then search it many times.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Views"); //path to start searching.
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    ProcessDirectory(path);
}
//Loop through each file and directory of provided path.
public void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
{
     // Process the list of files found in the directory.
     string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
     foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
     {
          string found = ProcessFile(fileName);
     }
     //Recursive loop through subdirectories of this directory.
     string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
     foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
     {
          ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
     }
}
//Get contents of file and search specified text.
public string ProcessFile(string filepath)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    string strWordSearched = "test";

    using (var stream = new StreamReader(filepath))
    {
         content = stream.ReadToEnd();
         int index = content.IndexOf(strWordSearched);
         if (index > -1)
         {
              return Path.GetFileName(filepath);
         }
     } 
 }
```